# Display the output in Android app using XSLT in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am using new bee for Phonegap and already built one mobile app. I want to use Phonegap with xslt as a display. Can u please suggest how to do that with Phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to use XSLT to turn XML into HTML and show on the screen, using Phonegap? I think you just need to look for Javascript tutorials on XSL. If you are familiar with jquery this will be even easier.

Never mind Phonegap as your script will be the same: take document, apply transform, and place results into a `<div>`.